# Keras issue with top k categorical accuracy with 3d tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having trouble with the top k categorical accuracy metric in keras. I'm training on genomic data, with about 10,000 individuals, each individual has a stretch of 4,000 nucleotides that can be one of four bases, so they are one hot encoded. The output is similar, but instead of four bases, there are three categories.

input shape (10000, 4000, 4)
output shape (10000, 4000, 3)

I try to use top k categorical accuracy, but I get:
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'metrics/top_k_categorical_accuracy/in_top_k/InTopKV2' (op: 'InTopKV2') with input shapes: [?,?,3], [?,?], [].

Evidently keras doesn't like the 3d tensor. How do I get around this?

Comment: Why the downvote? It is really an error that I don't know how to resolve. Is the question too ambiguous or something?

Comment: I usually include the code I used.
Not a good reason for downvoting, in my opinion, but still, it's usually recommended to do so.

Comment: Ok thanks for replying. I was genuinely puzzled by the initial downvote but it's good to have some feedback.

Comment: You are welcome.
Of course, this is only speculation on my part, as I did not downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100322/top-k-categorical-accuracy-for-time-distributed-lstm-results/58102380#58102380) might help you.

Simply put, top k categorical accuracy was not defined to be dimensionally flexible.

You need to transform the data to fit.

```
import keras.backend as K 
def my_top_k(true, pred, num):
    true = K.reshape(true, (-1, features_num))   
    pred = K.reshape(pred, (-1, features_num))
    return top_k_categorical_accuracy(true, pred, k=num)
```